# Scanner.hasNextLine() method is not seeing next lines in the file

Tags: java, xml

I have the following code:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner (file);
while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
     System.out.println ("Next line");
     String line = scanner.nextLine();

}
```

At first the print statement never executed. I thought that was odd because the file is an xml file with about 2,000 lines. For kicks I tried inserting the following before initializing the Scanner object:

```
try{
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
} catch (Exception e){}
```

When I ran the program, the file was opened AND the print statement executed all 2,000 times (meaning scanner.hasNextLine() worked). I thought it was an issue pertaining to permissions so commented out the code above and I tried:

```
file.setWritable(true);
file.setExecutable(true);
file.setReadable(true);
```

scanner.hasNextLine() went back to not working and the print statement was never executed. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

entire function looks like this:

```
public void addToList (File file){
    try{
        file.setWritable(true);
        file.setExecutable(true);
        file.setReadable(true);

        if (file.exists())
            System.out.println("File exists");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (file, "UTF-8");
        int lineCount=0;
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
            System.out.println("Next line");
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
        }

    }

    catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        System.err.println (e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

where file is an absolute path

Comment: Sounds strange as the code itself works on my end like it should. Try to enclose the problem. Are you able to read the file with other methods like `FileReader` or Javas **NIO** `Files` class? How do you create the **file** object? Are you sure that it points to the correct file, do the methods on file work, like `File#getName`? Is something unusual about the file or your system? Can you reproduce the problem with a smaller example file? If yes, show us the file please. Does the problem also occur with other files or just this one?

Comment: I know for sure that the file exists because I create it within my program and I am able to view it in my file system afterwards. 

So what I basically do is I fish an ichat file from my file system, create an xml file out of it, and put it in /Users/me/directory/ and I am passing that file to my addtoList method so that I can parse through it (which is why I'm using a scanner to go through it line-by-line). I made another java file away from my project and used the same method except I hard coded the absolute path  and passed that directly to the function and it worked for some reason.

Comment: The `file.exists()` test is pointless. If it doesn't exist, a `FileNotFoundException` will be thrown. You're forcing the system to test it twice.

Answer (score 0):

You used a `try`, but never caught anything, which could be the issue. When I added a catch and ran this code with a `xml` file it worked fine:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    addToList(new File("/Users/[YourName]/Desktop/[FileName].xml"));
}

public static void addToList (File file){
    try{
        file.setWritable(true);
        file.setExecutable(true);
        file.setReadable(true);

        if (file.exists())
            System.out.println("File exists");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (file, "UTF-8");
        int lineCount=0;
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
            System.out.println("Next line");
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was originally passing absolute paths to the method containing my code but after reading this post, I hard coded the location of one of my files and it worked. Very weird.

Comment: @an0therlurker so did this answer solve your problem? You can accept and/or upvote any helpful answers to your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately no. My full method looks like this: 

    public void addToList (File file){
  
    try {

    System.out.println("Current file: " +file.toString());
    file.setWritable(true);
    file.setExecutable(true);
    file.setReadable(true);
    if (file.exists())
        System.out.println("File exists");

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner (file, "UTF-8");
    int lineCount=0;
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
        System.out.println("Next line");
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
    }

Comment: Sorry for the ugly format. I updated my original post with the code above. It works when I hard code an absolute file in but if I try to pass an existing file in through the method, it doesn't work. The file for sure exists because the exists function works and because when I pass it into Desktop.getDesktop.open(file), it opens the file

Comment: @an0therlurker You used `try`, but never caught anything. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Oops sorry, forgot to include it

Comment: @an0therlurker I just edited my post. If this doesn't work then there's something wrong with your IDE or your file, or the way you call the method.

Comment: Nope. Still banging my head with it

Comment: @an0therlurker hmmm... sorry. Try it on another IDE. Is there any chance you could post a link to the file?

Answer (score -1):

You haven't printed your line. After making `String line` and assigning it the value of `scanner.nextLine()`, it is left unused. Try printing the line like this:

```
System.out.println("Next line" + line);
```

Comment: This does not answer the OP's problem. Regardless it should still print "Next line" 2000 times.